# Journey Builder vs. Normal Send - Synchronized DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, automationstudio, marketing-cloud-connect

I just setup Marketing Cloud Connect and am querying data from a parent account to a child BU using shared data extensions/query activities. In this instance, I am also pulling in newsletter subscription statuses to the child business unit. If the sends are to come from the child business unit, would it make more sense to create a Journey or use some regular automations to segment that data and send weekly, monthly, quarterly newsletters using guided sends?

Ideally this data would also reflect in sales cloud with tracking related data which was setup through the connector i.e. contact opened and clicked the weekly newsletter article etc. These newsletters are also maintained regularly and don't need to be triggered by a salesforce event, just sent as we dictate.

Just weighing my options/path of least resistance thanks!

Comment: Use Salesforce Sends from Automations to get your Individual Email Results in Sales Cloud. The rest is subjective. Reasons for JB vs Automations... where you have things like multiple email fields in your CRM data and you'd like to send to specific ones for particular sends or there are other pieces of automation you'd like to perform from JB using Salesforce Activities. Unit testing's easier with AS, as a general rule and it's bloody fast at sending to very large audiences. Just looking at an automation, more or less pauses it and you'll forget to reenable it and Journey Builder has versions.

Comment: Using Automation Studio to accomplish this, would I also be able to store tracking results within marketing cloud in the tracking folder?

Comment: Yes, so long as you use Salesforce Send activities to send your emails and use Data Extensions placed in your Salesforce Data Extensions folders as your audiences.